# Neglecting higher order terms in expansion

Tags: calculus, approximation

Suppose we have a function $v$ of $x$ with a minimum at $x=0$. We have, for $x$ close to zero, $$v'(x) = v'(0) +xv''(0) +\frac{x^2}{2}v'''(0)+\cdots$$ Then as $v'(0)=0$ $$v'(x)\approx xv''(0)$$ if $$|xv'''(0)|\ll v''(0)$$

Which is fine. I am unable to understand this statement:

> Typically each extra derivative will bring with it a factor of $1/L $
>   where $L$ is the distance over which the function changes by a large
>   fraction. So $$x\ll L$$

This is extracted from a physics derivation, and I cannot get how they tacked on a factor of $1/L$

Comment: Source is [Howard Georgi's Physics of Waves](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/new.htm) page 7 (1.26) in the online edition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rule of thumb rather than a rigorous statement (which is indicated by the word "typically"). Just look at $v(x)=\sin\frac xL$. The length on which this function changes noticeably is of order $L$. Now try to differentiate a few times. The next exercise is to take an arbitrary smooth function $V$ and stretch it $L$ times horizontally to get $v(x)=V(x/L)$. Now the change in $V$ that you felt at distance $1$ is felt at distance $L$ in $v$. Try to differentiate here. I doubt anything much more profound than this simple scaling observation was meant.

Answer (score 0):

If each derivative contributes $\frac{1}{L}$,  then $|xv'''| << v'' \implies  x(\frac{1}{L})^3 << (\frac{1}{L})^2$.  Divide both sides by $(\frac{1}{L})^3$ and this becomes  $x << L$.

That $\frac{1}{L}$ term is refering to the change in the function according to the difference method of derivatives (Definition via difference quotients) [given in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative). If you calculate out the quotient between the second and third derivatives (or first and second), it should approximate to the result above given the context.